# Radical ideal of $\langle x+y+z, -xy+yz+z^2 \rangle$

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

Let $I=\langle x+y+z, -xy+yz+z^2 \rangle \subset k[x,y,z]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Finding the radical of $\sqrt{I}$ is equivalent to finding $I(V(I))$ by the Nullstellenstz. We have

$$
V(I)=V(x+y+z) \cap V(-xy+yz+z^2)
$$

The equation $x+y+z=0$ gives $z=-x-y$, which can be plugged into $-xy+yz+z^2=0$ to obtain

$$
-xy+y(-x-y)+(x+y)^2=-2xy-y^2+x^2+2xy+y^2=0
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
x^2=0
$$
so that $x=0$. Then we get

$$
V(I)=\{ (0,a,-a)\in k^3: a\in k\}
$$
and

$$
I(V(I))=\langle x, y+z \rangle=\sqrt{I}
$$

Is that right? What can be done without the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it can be done without the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed. Suppose that $p$ is a prime ideal containing $I$. Your computation shows that 
$$
(x+y+z, -xy + yz + z^2, x^2) \subset p.
$$
Using that $p$ is prime, this inclusion implies that 
$$
(x+y+z, -xy + yz + z^2, x) = (y+z, yz + z^2, x) = (y+z, z(y+z), x) = (y+z, x)
$$
is also in $p$. Since $(y+z,x)$ is prime, it is the radical of $I$.